# Show video while saving it

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, gstreamer

I have a folder full of images, I need to save these images into the video while doing so I want to show the user the video being played from these images (frames). I can run two separate processes one for the saving and one for the showing but this is not what I am looking for, I want to do both in one step. If you know a solution please let me know.

My code uses C++ with OpenCV but feel free to share with me any code written with any language, or event a concept.

I use gStreamer, ffmpeg as well for the video generation, so I am not looking how to save a video or how to show the video I am looking for a process that can do both in one operation.

Comment: [mre] is required.

Comment: you know... you should just use ffmpeg, if the task is turning a pile of pictures into a video. why do you need to show the video as it encodes? OpenCV is for computer vision, not for video encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's my quick brew using [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/). You have to link SFML and include the include folder. Simply set `directory` to your target folder, I use [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) to add all files from that folder to a `std::vector<std::string>`.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

void add_frame_to_video(std::string path) {
    //your encoding stuff ...
}

int main() {
    auto dimension = sf::VideoMode(1280u, 720u);
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    window.create(dimension, "Video Rendering");

    sf::Texture frame_texture;

    std::vector<std::string> frame_paths;

    std::string directory = "resources/";
    for (auto i : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(directory)) {
        frame_paths.push_back({ i.path().string() });
    }

    std::size_t frame_ctr = 0u;
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        if (frame_ctr >= frame_paths.size()) {
            window.close();
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        const auto& current_frame = frame_paths[frame_ctr];

        add_frame_to_video(current_frame);

        if (!frame_texture.loadFromFile(current_frame)) {
            std::cout << "Error: couldn't load file \"" << current_frame << "\".\n";
            window.close();
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        sf::Sprite frame_sprite;
        frame_sprite.setTexture(frame_texture);
        ++frame_ctr;

        window.clear();
        window.draw(frame_sprite);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

this will create a window that shows each picture per frame using `sf::Texture` to load and `sf::Sprite` to display the image. If no more frames are available, the window gets closed and the program terminates. If you want to add time between frames, you can set e.g. `window.setFramerateLimit(10);` to have 10 frames / second.

Comment: It does work however there is a flicker in the window that is shown. Is there a way that I can clear this flickering noise?!

Comment: A flicker after each frame?

Comment: you don't need this "SFML" thing. just stick with OpenCV. it can show "video" well enough, and it takes care of flickering/buffering for you.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz
You mean I use imshow() and imwrite() instead of the SFML?!

Comment: imshow and waitkey, yes, but not imwrite, that's for images. VideoWriter is for video writing.